# How do I change the font size of product titles on this website through WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to change the font size of the product titles from 14px to 18px or higher. Not sure yet.

Here is how the code looks when I inspect it:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
.woocommerce .product-title-link {
    font-size: 14px !important;
```

I would like to change the font size using custom css in WordPress.

[image: product title]

In custom css, the code doesn't translate.

Here is the website: https://www.infinitybellatrend.com/shop/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .woocommerce .product-title-link {
        font-size: 18px !important;
    }
}
```

You need a opening `{` and closing `}` for de media query.